# Best Practise to handle listeners for a UICollectionView feed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, listener

I'm trying to finding the right approach for the following scenario:

I have `UICollectionView` which display objects (with UNIQUE ID's). Each user can "modify" the object, so obviously all the others users at the same moment needs to see this change.

The question is this, **should i listen to the parent `Value` of this objects,which contain all of the objects(which sounds like waste of "request time",because sometimes users will listen to changes they don't need(in case the collectionView filtered), Or should i set up a bunch of (single)listeners, only to the "specific" objects currently needed?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the child events to process updates to single child nodes.

```
// save updates a dictionary with the snapshot key 
// being the dictionary key
var items = [String: FDataSnapshot]()
let ref = Firebase(url: "<my-firebase-app>")
// listen to various child events and update the data source
ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in
  items[snap.key] = snap
}
ref.observeEventType(.ChildChanged) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in
  items[snap.key] = snap
}
ref.observeEventType(.ChildRemoved) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in
  items.removeValueForKey(snap.key)
}
```

> ...should i listen to the parent Value of this objects,which contain
>   all of the objects(which sounds like waste of "request time"

It's important to **not think in terms of requests**. Firebase uses WebSockets. Once the WebSocket is established it's holds a persistent connection to the server. Sending data back and forth the socket requires little overhead.

**[But, I would actually use FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-ios)**, which is a library for synchronizing Firebase data to UITableView's and UICollectionView's.

```
let firebaseRef = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/")
let dataSource: FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource!
...
self.dataSource = FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource(ref: self.firebaseRef, cellReuseIdentifier: "<YOUR-REUSE-IDENTIFIER>", view: self.collectionView)

self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UICollectionViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
  let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot

  // Populate cell as you see fit, like as below
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}

self.collectionView.dataSource = self.dataSource
```

Comment: Wow David! Thank you so much! Help me a tons. Definitely i would checking this out. I have a few more question, is it possible for a quick chat just to shut my curious mind?

Comment: I would love to answer any questions you have, but the SO comments section is not the best medium. Feel free to ask another question on SO and I'll do my best to answer!

Comment: Ah awesome, I will :) just came to my mind. Is it possible to create chat room? i'll make a blog post over all the conclusions as well(so others devs could enjoy)

Comment: I think to get a chat room

Comment: You need to have a bunch of comments

Comment: Because then it'll suggest that you

Comment: More comments is gold!

Comment: Extend the conversation in a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99965/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-david-east).